# Spring not injecting @value annotation in property

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class:

```java
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Value("${build.version}")
    private String buildVersion;

    public void test() {
         System.out.println(this.buildVersion);
    }

}
```

I am calling the method test() from a controller:

```java
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public StatusResponse status() {
        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        scheduler.update();
    }
```

However spring is not injecting the `build.version` value even though the class has a `@Component` annotation.

I am using the same property in a controller and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything is correct in the definition. I also tried it out just in case and it works. I used the .properties file. You need to post more code in order to help you more

Comment: How is `Scheduler` used, and where is `#test()` being called?

Comment: You must @Autowired Scheduler, not create an instance with new, as Spring takes cares of the class managing

Comment: Why not autowiring Scheduler class instead of creating new?

Comment: I am not sure what @Autowired means

Comment: Should autowire scheduler and why is your test in a @Component? Mark it @SpringBootTest so it picks up the context and define a property in application.properties called build.version. Check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K43qyHJXmWI to learn about autowiring will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this way, as you create instance with new instead of rely on Spring object managing(Inversion of control)

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {


   private Scheduler scheduler;

   @Autowired
   public ApiController(Scheduler scheduler) {
      this.scheduler = scheduler 
   }

   @GetMapping("/status")
   public StatusResponse status() {
      scheduler.update();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `application.yml` to provide value to these properties then use `@ConfigurationProperties` on top of the class. You do not need to give `@Value` on every property value, for example:

```
@Component
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "build")
public class SchedulerProperties {

    private String buildVersion;

}
```

In `application.yml` define as below

```
build:
  buildVersion: "XYZ"
```

Then you can just call version from the properties class

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

   @Autowired
   private SchedulerProperties schedulerProperties;

    public void test() {
         System.out.println(schedulerProperties.getBuildVersion());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not using any application.yml, just spring's magic.